# How to run correctly wordpress cron from Cpanel

Tags: wp-cron

I'm trying to set cron from cpanel.
I use that command `0,30**** wget -q -O - https://www.mysite.it/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`
in the cron settings of siteground cpanel. But it seems not to work. Plugin stop to work.

I'm using also "WP-Cron Status Checker" plugin to check if cron is working. If I use the string https://www.mysite.it/wp/wp-cron.php?setcronjob on browser, the cron work perfectly and is detected by plugin, but with the cpanel scheduler, it is not detected and plugin aren't working. What to try?

Comment: what is the plugin you're referring to? Keep in mind your cron URL looks right, but 3rd party plugin support is off topic here

Comment: Several plugins don't work. But if I use manual url they work correctly. This manual url is not the same of server command? I need to use a different cron command to make plugin work? This part is not so clear for me. Plugin use different cron or the cron is always the same? And if they use different cron, why manual executing the wp cron they work correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by manual URL vs non-manual URL, there's only a single URL for wp-cron, `example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`, there are no other URLs. If you're referring to other options then those options are not common knowledge or standard WordPress. As an aside, is this a multisite install? You have to call `wp-cron.php` on each individual site, hitting the URL of the root blog only runs cron for the root blog. Note that it is not the plugins job to detect a cron URL hit, it is WordPress' responsibility. Any plugin that performs that kind of check is doing things wrong

Comment: Also, which are the plugins you're referring to? If you don't want to share their names you should say so, but this is important information. It may not be possible to answer this question without it. Even if you think it's not important, share it anyway to confirm that is the case.

Comment: Plugins are "Auto Post Scheduler" or "FS Poster" also "One Signal" for example. If I use this link https://www.mysite.it/wp/wp-cron.php?setcronjob from browser, they are all working fine. Every time I use this url I see from "Wp Cron Status" plugin that the cron is running correctly as you can see from the screen there [link](http://prntscr.com/v1r8u3). But the plugin instead don't detect cron running from siteground Cpanel setting.

Comment: the cron status will not tell you if CPanel is triggering WP Cron correctly, much in the way that a mechanic can tell you that your car is in perfect working order, that doesn't mean you can enter it via the sunroof. The correct parameter is `doing_wp_cron`, here is the proof: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-cron.php#L91

Comment: That code does suggest you might have a cron lock in place that has not been cleared, but the timeout for cron locks is 60 secnds, are you sure there are no PHP fatal errors happening or that have happened during cron jobs? What happens if you manually trigger WP Cron via WP CLI? I ***guarantee*** you that `wp-cron.php?setcronjob` is incorrect, whoever suggested that is incorrect

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure your cron entry is valid? It looks very weird having all those parameters without separating spaces. E.g. for my site I used to have `*/5 * * * * wget -q -O – https://tomjn.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`